# Dynamically printing out XML according to the number of items in an array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have a function that is generating XML for a contract last web service(not my choice).

```
    public function generateXml($endorsements)
    {
     $xmlstr = '
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <is:CaptureRQ xmlns:dg="urn:digimarc.com:SchemaTypes" DataVersion="1.6" XsdSchemaValidatable="true" xmlns:is="urn:digimarc.com:imaging">
       <is:Endorsements>
        <is:Code>
         <dg:Value>'.$endorsements.'</dg:Value> 
        </is:Code>
       </is:Endorsements>
      </is:CaptureRQ>';
     return $xmlstr;
    }
```

The thing is, the `$endorsements` variable is an array.  For every item in the array I need to create a new element:

```
<is:Endorsements>
         <is:Code>
           <dg:Value>'.$endorsements.'</dg:Value> 
         </is:Code>
</is:Endorsements>
```

I know ths is a hacked up way of doing things, but I've been locked into this by the vendor.  I'm really not sure how to do this.  Thank you guys for your help in advance.

**Further Example**

Just to be clear, here's an example.

```
generateXml(array(a,b,c));
```

Would output:

```
<is:Endorsements>
   <is:Code>
     <dg:Value>a</dg:Value> 
   </is:Code>
</is:Endorsements>
<is:Endorsements>
   <is:Code>
     <dg:Value>b</dg:Value> 
   </is:Code>
</is:Endorsements>
<is:Endorsements>
   <is:Code>
     <dg:Value>c</dg:Value> 
   </is:Code>
</is:Endorsements>
```

Where a smaller array would be:

```
generateXml(array(a,b));
```

This would output:

```
<is:Endorsements>
   <is:Code>
     <dg:Value>a</dg:Value> 
   </is:Code>
</is:Endorsements>
<is:Endorsements>
   <is:Code>
     <dg:Value>b</dg:Value> 
   </is:Code>
</is:Endorsements>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hows this?

```
public function generateXml($endorsements) {

foreach( (array)$endorsements as $endorsement ) {
    $endorsementsXML[] = '
    <is:Endorsements>
    <is:Code>
    <dg:Value>'.$endorsement.'</dg:Value> 
    </is:Code>
    </is:Endorsements>
    ';
}

return '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<is:CaptureRQ xmlns:dg="urn:digimarc.com:SchemaTypes" DataVersion="1.6"             XsdSchemaValidatable="true" xmlns:is="urn:digimarc.com:imaging">

'.implode("\n", (array)$endorsementsXML).'

</is:CaptureRQ>';

}
```

Comment: I need to have multiple endorsement elements in one xml document.  Meaning if I pass array(a,b) into the function I get <is:Endorsements> and every thing in between for both the a and the b.  The only difference being their value.

Comment: Updated.  Thank you for your help so far leenix

Comment: No probs. The code i gave you would work perfect with your examples. Just a little tweak to it i think. Hows that?

Comment: When I try to run it by:
generateXml(array(a,b));
I get the error: Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a'

Comment: I wasn't quoting the values in the array.  It works.  Thank you!